# How to get cache on created form in acumatica

Tags: c#, acumatica

Hello i am new in acumatica development i have created a new formview which i want to get the cache of my custom form but i dont get the Base of it

```
SOtemptemp items = (SOtemptemp)Base.MasterView.Current;
```

it does not recognize the Base of my formview the thing the i want to accomplish is i want to get the textfield value on action click. here is a sanpshot of my form

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SOtemptemp DAC - most likely - is associated to a new Data view.
If that is the case, you don't need the "Base" reference to access the current value. You could use `SOtemptemp items = (SOtemptemp)this.MasterView.Current;` directly